# Observablearray length evaluating to 0 despite having data when sorting

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

EDIT Here is my drop down list from the view-

```
                 <div class="ToolBox" style="height: 30px; width: 100%">
                <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sort By:&nbsp;</b>
                <select id="ddlSortBy" style="margin-top: 0px; height: 24px; width: 160px !important"
                    data-bind="value: serverSelectedOptionID, options: serverOptions, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'">
                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img data-bind="click: SortUpDownAllCerts" src="/Content/images/updownarrow.bmp" style="padding-bottom: 4px; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle;" />
            </div>
```

In my view, I am displaying the length of an observableArray-

```
 My Certificates&nbsp;(<span data-bind="text: allCertificates().length"></span>)
```

If I sort the observableArray using the below code, the length of the allCertificates observableArray shows 0 (66 records do display on the screen, so the length of the observableArray should be 66)-

```
        serverSelectedOptionID.subscribe(function () {
        var sortCriteriaID = serverSelectedOptionID._latestValue;
        allCertificates.sort(function (a, b) {
            var fieldname = serverOptions[sortCriteriaID-1].OptionText;
            allCertificates.valueHasMutated();
            if (a[fieldname] == b[fieldname]) {
                return a[fieldname] > b[fieldname] ? 1 : a[fieldname] < b[fieldname] ? -1 : 0;
            }

            return a[fieldname] > b[fieldname] ? 1 : -1;

        });

    });
```

If I comment out the above code, the allCertificates observableArray shows 66 as the length just like it should.

For completeness, here is the entire viewmodel code-

```
 define(['services/logger', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/CertificateDataService'],
function (logger, system, router, CertificateDataService) {
    var allCertificates = ko.observableArray([]);
    var myCertificates = ko.observableArray([]);
    var serverSelectedOptionID = ko.observableArray();

    var serverOptions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Certificate', OptionText: 'lwCertID' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Client Name', OptionText: 'clientName' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Client Number', OptionText: 'clientNumber' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Request Date', OptionText: 'requestDate' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Collateral Analyst', OptionText: 'userName' }
    ];

    var serverSelectedOptionID = ko.observable();

    var activate = function () {

        // go get local data, if we have it
        return SelectAllCerts(), SelectMyCerts();

    };


    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        allCertificates: allCertificates,
        myCertificates: myCertificates,
        title: 'Certificate Approvals',
        SelectMyCerts: SelectMyCerts,
        SelectAllCerts: SelectAllCerts,
        theOptionId: ko.observable(1),
        serverOptions: serverOptions,
        serverSelectedOptionID: serverSelectedOptionID
    };

    serverSelectedOptionID.subscribe(function () {
        var sortCriteriaID = serverSelectedOptionID._latestValue;
        allCertificates.sort(function (a, b) {
            var fieldname = serverOptions[sortCriteriaID-1].OptionText;
            allCertificates.valueHasMutated();
            if (a[fieldname] == b[fieldname]) {
                return a[fieldname] > b[fieldname] ? 1 : a[fieldname] < b[fieldname] ? -1 : 0;
            }

            return a[fieldname] > b[fieldname] ? 1 : -1;

        });

    });

    function getFieldNameByOptionID(OptionID) {

    }


    return vm;

    function SortUpDownAllCerts() {
        return allCertificates.sort()
    }

    function SortUpDownMyCerts() {
        return allCertificates.sort()
    }


    function SelectAllCerts() {
        return CertificateDataService.getallCertificates(allCertificates);
    }

    function SelectMyCerts() {
        return CertificateDataService.getMyCertificates(myCertificates);
    }
});
```

How can I get this to work? Why does it evaluate to 0 and not 66?

Comment: Any reason you are calling valueHasMutated() inside of the sort function instead of after sorting is complete?

Comment: I tried it outside as well. Was trying anything.  I am new to knockout.  Hoping it is something simple I have not learned yet.

Comment: I have been using Knockout for quite some time now and have never had to use valueHasMutated (Knockout lets all subscribers know already)  Looking at your code earlier it definitely took me extra time to understand because there are no comments explaining why you are doing what you are doing.  I will look at it again in a bit and see what we can come up with.  I have not yet been able to figure out why you are using _latestValue instead of just () though, for reference serverSelectedID() returns the current value.

Comment: Thanks Kadumel.  I got rid of _latestValue and valueHasMutated.  I am new to knockout, so that is why you saw _latestValue.  Thanks for looking, still stuck.

Comment: Sounds like you are getting on the right path.  The problem now is that I am not sure what problem you are having with your solution besides that an observableArray().length === 0.  It doesn't seem to make sense given the context.  I make a jsFiddle out of what you posted and it seems to be working ok.  Can you try to make a fiddle out of your code so I can see your problem a bit better?

Comment: I created the fiddle, however the fiddle ran without problems-    http://jsfiddle.net/wood0615/VzER2/  .  Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Spoke to soon.  As soon as I added subscribe, the length went to 0. See the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/wood0615/VzER2/

Answer (score 0):

You are going to hate yourself for this -

http://jsfiddle.net/VzER2/15/

The only problem in your code was this

```
<h2 data-bind="text: title()"></h2>Length: <span data-bind="text: allCertificates().length"></span>
```

You had allCertificates.length instead of allCertificates().length.  When you are in the view and using a data-bind it unwraps your observable for you.  But if you need to get a property of that observable you need to call it again.

If there is something else that is not working let me know, I haven't tried changing the value of serverSelectedID

Comment: Thanks kadumel.  I left  allCertificates().length out of the fiddle, but not my original post.  The fiddle works now, but not my app.   allCertificates().length continues to show 0, and i cannot reproduce it in fiddle.

Comment: Hmm when should subscribe be firing?  I dont see any changes to the id or select lists to change?

Comment: I updated the post to include the select list.  It fires when the view is first loaded.

Comment: I added your drop down to the fiddle and I still don't see any problems - http://jsfiddle.net/VzER2/17/

Comment: Strange, but it does not work in the app, but does in fiddle.  Thanks for the efforts.  I will keep looking and post the answer when I find it.

Comment: One thing to note is I have removed alot of the 'junk' markup that should be taken care if with styling, and also in the view model I made some changes to use self in place of this or nothing at all to ensure context is persisted.